# Volume of revolution of $x=a(​\theta+\sin​ \theta)$ and $y=a(1+cos​θ)$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the volume of the solid formed when a curve whose $x$ and $y$ coordinates are parametrically given as $x=a(​\theta+\sin​ \theta)$ and $y=a(1+cos​θ)$ is rotated about it's base.

Could someone help me with this? Do we first need to eliminate $\theta$ because that does not seem possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \int \pi y^2 \, dx =\int\, \pi y(\theta)^2 \, (dx/d\theta) \,d\theta$$

So need not *a priori* eliminate $\theta$.